# MSVC std::_Pad no virtual destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, windows-8

I'm using

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x64
```

and when I do

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
```

I get

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(172) : error C4265: 'std::_Pad' : class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual
         instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
```

do I need to upgrade to  a newer version of MSVC?

Comment: [This appears to be intentional](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809540/c-warnings-in-stl-thread).

Comment: @T.C. wish I could downvote your comment as that URL is now dead. and you should have copied the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to update.

It is a warning that could be important when using virtual functions. If you allocate memory in a derived class you need a virtual destructor and freeing the memory on object destruction. Using std::mutex you are safe (huge disclaimer here).

You get rid of this warning by using *#pragma warning*. If you treat warnings as errors you have to get rid of it but never lower the compiler warnings level:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4265)
#include <mutex>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Surround the warning with care, you don't want to disable warnings for the whole file, you might miss some essential warning.